# A question about irreducible, reversible Markov chains and their time-continuous counterpart

Tags: probability, functional-analysis, stochastic-processes, markov-chains, stochastic-differential-equations

So let $(X_n^x)_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ be a $\pi$-reversible, irreducible Markov chain on some state space $E$ with transition probabilities $q(x,y)$ with starting point x. Note that $\pi$ is the stationary distribution.

Define the operators (for $f:E \to \mathbb{R}$)
$$
[Qf](x) = \sum_{y \in E}f(y)q(x,y) \\
[Lf](x) = [(Q - I)f](x) = \sum_{y \in E}(f(y) - f(x))q(x,y)
$$

These operators are self-adjoint and contractions on $L_2(\pi)$.
Now the paper I'm reading says that we can implicitly define the time-continuous Markov chain $(Y_t)_{t \ge0}$ by the "Fokker-Planck equation"
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial t}[P_{s,t}f](x) = [P_{s,t}[Lf]](x) \;\;\;\;\;\;\ s>t$$
$$[P_{s,s}f](x) := f(x)$$

with $[P_{s,t}f](x) = \sum_{y \in E}f(y)P(x,y)$ being the operator defined by $P_{s,t}(x,y)$ which is the transition probability for starting at time $s$ and point $x$ and arrive at time $t$ at $y$. So these transition probabilites by this differential equation. The paper says the following on how to interpret the new time-continuous Markov chain:
"If the process is at site x, then it waits an exponential time with mean one and at the
end of that time it chooses a site y with probability $q(x,y)$ and attempts to move
there."

The [paper](https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007/BF01224127.pdf) I'm refering to.
My question now is how do they come up with this interpretation of the new Markov chain by looking at this differential equation from above? I think I also miss some knowledge on this functional analysis approach to study Markov chains and I'd appreciate some literature tips, if you have some.